# How to make mapView and segmentedControl move relative to AdMob adaptive banner

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, admob, banner

I'm adding an adaptive banner ad from AdMob to the bottom of a `mapView` in my iOS app. No problem adding it, but the banner obscures both a `segmentedControl` which is placed at the bottom of the mapView. (Both the `mapView` and the `segmentedControl` are inside a `tabBarController`, all created in Storyboard.) The ad also covers the Apple Mags logo and "Legal" information - not sure if Apple will have a problem with that.

[Image example - top of segmentedControl barely visible under ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlvB3.jpg)

How can I make the `mapView` shift up by the same amount of space taken up by the ad, so as to make the `segmentedControl` and Apple Maps boilerplate visible, and not shift up at all if no ad is loaded? (Or is there another best practice of handling this?)

All my AdMob code is from the official AdMob tutorial:

```
func getAdaptiveSize() -> GADAdSize {

       var frame: CGRect

       if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        frame = view.frame.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets)
       } else {
           frame = view.frame
       }
       let viewWidth = frame.size.width

       return adSize
   }



func loadAdaptiveBannerAd(){
      bannerView.adSize = getAdaptiveSize()
      bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}

func addBannerToView(){
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

            bannerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        ])
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2435281174"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.backgroundColor = .darkGray

    addBannerToView()

}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewDidAppear(animated)
      loadAdaptiveBannerAd()
}
```

My hunch is that I have to fix this not by changing the placement of the ad banner itself, but by approaching either the `mapView` or the `superview` somehow, but I haven't found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your actual layout, but I'm going to assume it looks very close to this:

[image]

The Bottom of your `mapView` is constrained to the Bottom of the safe-area, and the Bottom of your Segmented control is constrained to the Bottom of the `mapView`. If you have your `SegControl` *also* constrained to the safe-area, change that to the `mapView` -- that way we only have to manipulate the `mapView` and the `SegControl` will move with it.

First step, change the Priority of the Map view's bottom constraint to `High (750)`:

[image]

and your constraints will look like this:

[image]

Next, connect that constraint to an `@IBOutlet`:

```
@IBOutlet var mapBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

result:

[image]

Now at run-time, when you add your banner view, add a ***NEW*** Bottom constraint to your map view:

```
func addBannerToView(){
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        bannerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        
        bannerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        
        // add this line
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bannerView.topAnchor)
        
    ])
}
```

Because the newly created constraint will have the default Priority of `Required (1000)`, auto-layout will "pin" the bottom of the map view to the top of the banner. Since we gave the Storyboard-created Bottom constraint a Priority of 750, we've told auto-layout it's allowed to *break* that constraint without causing conflicts.

If / when you remove the banner view, that "new" constraint will be removed with it, and the Storyboard-created constraint will again be used.

Comment: Great, that did it. Thank you for taking the time -- very clearly explained. Except for one thing I had to change: With a constraint of 750, the banner ad still obscured the segmented control at the bottom. However, I changed the constraint to 749 - and now the banner pushes the mapView and the segmentedControl upwards perfectly.